# Access user environment variable in Swift for macos

Tags: swift, macos, environment-variables

I'm developing console app for mac os in swift and i want to access user environment variables when calling bash command. I use the following code to run bash command in swift:

```
@discardableResult
func shell(_ command: String) -> String? {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = ["bash", "-c", command]
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

    return output
}
```

When i run `/usr/bin/env` in my terminal i see the desired variable but when i run `shell("/usr/bin/env")` in code i don't see one. The `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["MY_ENV_VAR"]` also don't show me the needed variable.
How to access user defined env vars in swift?

Comment: Do you execute the compiled program from the Terminal, or from within Xcode?

Comment: within Xcode, tried Debug executable/No Debug executable/Release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been struggling with a very similar problem recently. While I don't have a perfect solution for you, I do have some suggestions.

First, it really matters where exactly `MY_ENV_VAR` has been defined. If it is inside of a `.bashrc` file, you'll need to start up bash in interactive mode with `-i` so it reads that file. If it is defined in `.bash_profile`, you'll need use `-l` to start a so-called login shell.

In my particular case, I have to use *both* `-i` and `-l` to see the env vars I'm after. This all gets even more complex if the user doesn't use bash. I use fish, for example, so my required ENV variables aren't visible to bash at all, regardless of the `bash` invocation.

So, what I actually do is **first** determine what shell is being used, and then invoke that shell with `-i -l -c`. zsh, bash and fish all support these options.

It's a real pain, and I'm not even sure that method is reliable. But, it is working for me across a number of different user environments.

Comment: the -l is that what i've wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
```

Will give you the environment variables for the user which launch the app but Xcode don't launch the app with your rights and environment.

So for the testing phase you can define the needed variable in Xcode like the photo below

[image]

If you want to be sure, write the following code in a file (e.i: "main.swift"):

```
import Foundation

print(ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment)
```

And in a shell execute `swiftc main.swift` then `./main` and you will see the use variables

But you can use the **C** function `getenv`

- it take a `UnsafePointer<Int8>` which is the key you need (i.e: "HOME") : a C `char *`
- An return a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!` : The value

Comment: this is not exact answer. I need to access env from macos, from CI. In your solution its hardcoded in Xcode, so can be attacked by hacker and retrieved.

Comment: This is for Xcode env. But op want to access Mac's env like password stored in .zshrc or .bashrc.